# Transform output php

Tags: php

I have this, which is calling an integer value say: 2500.

```
echo "number_format({$row2['count(cID))";
```

This gives me an undesired output.

How do I fix this? How am i implementing the function wrong here? (I mean obviously I am)

Comment: Please edit your question and give us a little bit more code to work with. Is this inside a loop? And what is `cID`? Didn't you mean `$cID`? Also, `count()`ing `cID` is probably not what you want. But show us the code of the whole loop, if you can, so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I guessed right, you want something like this:

```
echo number_format($row2['count(cID)']);
```

I suppose you are getting a column from the database and calling it 'count(cID)', but it's really hard to know what you need. Try providing more details.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you mean

```
echo number_format($row2[count($cId)]);
```

?